# mysql can't create/write any file (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I'am new in mysql and I get stuck with this command.

```
select * into outfile '/home/<user_name>/Desktop/test1.csv' from my_table;
```

but mysql show

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/<user_name>/Desktop/test1.csv' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

how can I fix it ?

I'am using ubuntu 20.04
--> this my secure_file_priv

```
+------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                  |
+------------------+------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /home/<user_name>/Desktop/ |
+------------------+------------------------+
```

I also try disable appamor and make chmod 777 at Desktop folder but it doesn't work!

Comment: You need to make `/home/username/Desktop` world-writable so that the mysql daemon can create files there.